# Some propertis about a hilbert space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open domain in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ consisting of holomorphic functions.

a) Show that $\mathbb{H}$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$, and hence is a Hilbert space with inner product $(f,g)=\int_{\Omega}f(z)\overline{g}(z)dxdy,$ where $z=x+\mathrm{i}y$.

b) If $\{\phi_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{H}$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty|\phi_n(z)|^2\leq\frac{c^2}{d(z,\Omega^c)}, $ for $z\in\Omega$.

c) The sum $B(z,\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\phi_(z)\overline{\phi}_n(\omega)$ converges absolutly for $(z,\omega)\in\Omega\times\Omega$, and is independent of the choice of orthonormal basis.

Problem a) is an ordinary result of mean value property of holomorphic functions. For Problem b), I'm trying to apply cauchy integration fomula to get $d(z,\Omega^c)$, but in vain. I'm a bit confused by the sum of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty|\phi_n(z)|^2$. I also feel at loss when dealing with problem c)

Any solution or hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: any continuous linear form on $\mathbb{H}$ can be re-written as $f \longmapsto \langle f,\, g \rangle_{\mathbb{H}}$ (following your convention for the Hermitian product) for some function $g \in \mathbb{H}$.

In particular, show that the sums of b) and c) if you re-write thusly the linear form “evaluation at $z$” do not depend on the choice of the basis.

Show that c) stems from this and b). To show b), try and find whether there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{H}$ which makes the calculation of the sum easier.